# Mapas - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps

Pessoal eu estou usando a seguinte library para trabalhar com maps: http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library/ .

Aqui há o tutorial do mesmo: http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/mapclick .

Eu gostaria de quando eu clicasse no mapa não subisse um `alert`, mas sim que os dados fossem para 2 inputs. Para fazer subir o `alert` é usado o seguinte comando:

```
$config['onclick'] = 'alert(\'You just clicked at: \' + event.latLng.lat() + \', \' + event.latLng.lng());';
```

Mas eu não manjo muito de javascript e não faço ideia de como passar o valor para os 2 inputs, agradeço quem conseguir me ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar a função `val()` do [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Exemplo de script para jogar o valor no input(text-box) com Jquery

```
$("#txtLatitude").val(event.latLng.lat());
$("#txtLongitude").val(event.latLng.lng();
```

Com JavaScript puro

```
document.getElementById("txtLatitude").value = event.latLng.lat();
document.getElementById("txtLongitude").value = event.latLng.lng();
```

Ficaria assim sua configuração com Jquery

```
$config['onclick'] = '$("#txtLatitude").val(event.latLng.lat()); $("#txtLongitude").val(event.latLng.lng());';
```

Sua configuração com JavaScript puro:

```
 $config['onclick'] = 'document.getElementById("txtLatitude").value = event.latLng.lat();document.getElementById("txtLongitude").value = event.latLng.lng();';
```

Seus inputs teriam que ser assim para atender o exemplo, tendo que ter o atributo `id` para o jquery localizar o controle:

```
<input type="text" id="txtLatitude" name="latitude">
<input type="text" id="txtLongitude" name="longitude">
```